# How to upload multipe .mat files (Datasets) to R?

Tags: r, matlab, file-upload, dataset

I had a problem while uploading the .mat files to R. I searched and I found out that the problem is related the Matlab versions. However, I cannot change the version since I don't use Matlab (I didn't generate the data by myself). Could you please help me, solving this problem.
Thanks

Comment: What is the error and how did you upload that?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In order to ask a better question please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). What do you mean by *upload*? To read the data into an R session?